# Left and right continuity

Tags: analysis

I was wondering if someone can help me write down (or perhaps just check my answer) the proof for the following theorem formally. I feel that what I wrote down is too easy to be correct ...

Suppose that $f$ is defined over an open interval $I$ and $a\in I$. $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $f$ is both left and right continuous at a.

Proof: If $f$ is continuous at $a$, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$. Since this limit exists and equals $f(a)$ it must be the case that $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)=f(a)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=f(a)$. Hence $f$ is both left and right continuous at $a$. Conversely, if $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)=f(a)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=f(a)$ then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists and equals $f(a)$, hence $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Well, the proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're concluding what you want to prove without actually proving it. You might resort to epsilon-delta proofs. You will have a "left" delta and a "right" delta, so you will just need to let the "two-sided" delta be their minimum.

You're right, sometimes the obvious things are surprisingly elusive as proofs go.