# function limits and continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose for a function, $f(x)$, which is defined on $[a,b]$ and for some $p$ in $[a,b]$. If  $\lim_{x \to p_+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to p_-} f(x)$ are equal, say they are both $L$, am I therefore correct in concluding that $\lim_{x \to p} f(x)=L$. Also if $f(x)$ is continuous at $p$, is it true that then $f(p)=L$. 
(Also if I would like to prove the second statement, do I just use the definition of limit and continuity to prove it?)
Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left and right continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704657/left-and-right-continuity)

Answer (score 1):

Continuity of $f$ at $p$ is indeed achieved if and only if $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=f(p)$. (It is implicit that the limit must exist.)

If you compare the definitions of a limit and of continuity, you will notice that they just differ in $L$ vs. $f(p)$.